# Closed source plugins

Tags: qgis-plugins, license

Are you allowed to develop closed source, commercial plugins for QGIS?
License is GNU GPL, which is normally very restrictive.

Update: Assume it is a python plugin (possibly open-sourced), that call's a closed-source dll, which doesn't link to anything from QGIS.

Comment: Answered very well over at:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61065/qgis-plugin-licence

Comment: No, that doesn't cover the situation in my update.

Comment: The plugin itself would have to be open source as it would have to be GPL3 to communicate with QGIS, as outlined in the linked answer.

But you can for example: "Execute an external application, whatever its licence, from your plugin, exchanging data through files for example"

So it really depends what your .dll does.

Comment: The problem is a dll is normally not seen as an application, but rather a library. Which means this line from the question above becomes relevant: "You cannot link (as in compilation link) your plugin (c++ or python) with any proprietary or non-gpl compliant library." But calling a DLL (dynamically loaded) from python is that "linking"?

Comment: @UffeKousgaard You might be able to do that but you would have to get someone to check.

Answer (score 3):

No you can not close source a QGIS plugin.  All plugins must be GPL.

This is not to say you can't sell a plugin but being GPL means that who ever you sell it too can give it to someone else if they want.

Most plugins are also in Python which is readable as plain text.  You can develop a C++ plugin but they are also GPL and Python is a hell of lot easier.

Comment: Is this correct? It was my understanding that plgun licenses must "comply" with GPL V2 or later, not that they must "be" GPL. There are many  licenses including popular non-copyleft ones like Apache 2.0 or BSD 3 Clause that are GPL compatible.

Comment: No they must be GPL.   Plugins are derived works of QGIS have to have the GPL.  You can however link/include Apache code/libs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is incorrect. Please read https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLAndPlugins

Comment: @Luke don't think so "If the main program dynamically links plug-ins, and they make function calls to each other and share data structures, we believe they form a single combined program, which must be treated as an extension of both the main program and the plug-ins."

Comment: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/can-plugins-for-closed-source-software-use-gpld-libraries